# Check if error (error code) belongs to network errors

Tags: ios

The most important feature in my program is managing offline-online states of device and saving request for offline state / pushing them when online. So I got some experimentally gained error codes like -1009, -1001, -1003, -1005 each of corresponds to Network Error Code. Now I just check if obtained error's code is equal to one of these guys, but if there is smarter way? Perhaps list of network errors / special prefix / etc.

So, how to check if error describing network problem?

Comment: Why dont u use apple's reachability classes and add an observer for network status. Even before you make a web service call you will know whether you have network available or not. If its not available do not make a web service call and cache it for later use. It does not make sense to make web service call even if there is no network at all :) If you loose network while request in progress you will get time out error you can add all the HTTPS error code status which are universal and can handle them appropriately

Comment: @SandeepBhandari because I have such cases wich are not covered with reachability functionality. Rachability lets me know if I'm online or not, but what if I start sending request and become offline moments after sending? And there are many of such examples. But maybe this is a reason to check HTTP error codes, I need to think about it. Thanks, anyway

Comment: Thats what I meant when I said if you loose network while request in progress, you will get time out error. I am not really sure are these -1009 are universal error codes or only specific to apple. Using better work around to deal with network loss rather than using these hardcoded error states makes more sense

Comment: When I said work arounds : 1. If network call in progress and you happen to loose network, when you receive response obviously with error, your reachability would have already triggered and had told you about loss of networks. So in error block you can always check whether there was a loss of network availability and handle it appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone wants tune code according to error codes like I do, you're welcome (found in Foundation's NSURLError.h):

```
NS_ERROR_ENUM(NSURLErrorDomain)
{
    NSURLErrorUnknown =             -1,
    NSURLErrorCancelled =           -999,
    NSURLErrorBadURL =              -1000,
    NSURLErrorTimedOut =            -1001,
    NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL =          -1002,
    NSURLErrorCannotFindHost =          -1003,
    NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost =         -1004,
    NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost =       -1005,
    NSURLErrorDNSLookupFailed =         -1006,
    NSURLErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects =        -1007,
    NSURLErrorResourceUnavailable =         -1008,
    NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet =      -1009,
    NSURLErrorRedirectToNonExistentLocation =   -1010,
    NSURLErrorBadServerResponse =       -1011,
    NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication =     -1012,
    NSURLErrorUserAuthenticationRequired =  -1013,
    NSURLErrorZeroByteResource =        -1014,
    NSURLErrorCannotDecodeRawData =             -1015,
    NSURLErrorCannotDecodeContentData =         -1016,
    NSURLErrorCannotParseResponse =             -1017,
    NSURLErrorAppTransportSecurityRequiresSecureConnection API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.11), ios(9.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0)) = -1022,
    NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist =        -1100,
    NSURLErrorFileIsDirectory =         -1101,
    NSURLErrorNoPermissionsToReadFile =     -1102,
    NSURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.5), ios(2.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0)) =  -1103,
    NSURLErrorFileOutsideSafeArea API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.12.4), ios(10.3), watchos(3.2), tvos(10.2)) = -1104,

    // SSL errors
    NSURLErrorSecureConnectionFailed =      -1200,
    NSURLErrorServerCertificateHasBadDate =     -1201,
    NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted =  -1202,
    NSURLErrorServerCertificateHasUnknownRoot = -1203,
    NSURLErrorServerCertificateNotYetValid =    -1204,
    NSURLErrorClientCertificateRejected =   -1205,
    NSURLErrorClientCertificateRequired =   -1206,
    NSURLErrorCannotLoadFromNetwork =       -2000,

    // Download and file I/O errors
    NSURLErrorCannotCreateFile =        -3000,
    NSURLErrorCannotOpenFile =          -3001,
    NSURLErrorCannotCloseFile =         -3002,
    NSURLErrorCannotWriteToFile =       -3003,
    NSURLErrorCannotRemoveFile =        -3004,
    NSURLErrorCannotMoveFile =          -3005,
    NSURLErrorDownloadDecodingFailedMidStream = -3006,
    NSURLErrorDownloadDecodingFailedToComplete =-3007,

    NSURLErrorInternationalRoamingOff API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.7), ios(3.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0)) =         -1018,
    NSURLErrorCallIsActive API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.7), ios(3.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0)) =                    -1019,
    NSURLErrorDataNotAllowed API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.7), ios(3.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0)) =                  -1020,
    NSURLErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.7), ios(3.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0)) =      -1021,

    NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionRequiresSharedContainer API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.10), ios(8.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0)) = -995,
    NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionInUseByAnotherProcess API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.10), ios(8.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0)) = -996,
    NSURLErrorBackgroundSessionWasDisconnected API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.10), ios(8.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0))= -997,
};
```